# In Keras or in Tensorflow.Keras, the command "models.load_model" does absolutely nothing

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My saved keras model either doesn't load or it doesn't function.  I've tried both keras and tf.keras.

Python doesn't report any issues when I try to save the model.  Python doesn't report any issues when I try to load the model.  But when I try to use the model, it's as though the model doesn't exist.

I create a model in keras like so:

```
def modelsettings(self, InputSize, TotalActionCount, model, LearnRate):

        print("Settings ActionCount(+1): " + str(TotalActionCount))

        model = Sequential()    
        model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(InputSize, 1), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())  
        model.add(Dense(48, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))                           
        model.add(Dense(TotalActionCount + 1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='linear'))     
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I then train the model.  It works wonderfully.  No issues.

Then, I save the model with this method:

```
def SaveBrain(self, FileName, model):
        print("Saving: " + FileName)
        model.save(FileName)
```

When using keras, I get a single .h5 file.  When using tf.keras, I get a folder with the model stored inside.  I presume no problems.  (But I'm not sure.)

I then load the model with this method:

```
def LoadBrain(self, FileName, model):

        print("Loading: " + FileName)
        del model
        model = models.load_model(FileName, compile=True)

        return model
```

So far, I receive no errors from Python.  But when I try to use the model, I receive errors.  When trying to get the learning_rate, Python tells me that Nonetype has no learning_rate.  When I try to train_on_batch, Python tells me I need to first compile the model.

What is going on?  Extremely frustrating.

Thank you.

One of you asked for a more complete look at the code with locations that the errors occur.  Here is a closer look at the code.  To be clear, errors only occur after I load a saved model.  There are no errors of any kind when I create a new model.

```
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import copy
import json
import statistics



#Turn these on to switch back to Keras.
#from keras.models import Sequential      
#from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten  
#from keras import models
#from keras import optimizers
#from keras import backend

#Turn these off to switch back to Keras.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential      
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten  
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import backend


from collections import deque            

from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import cgi


class BrainFunctions():



    def initializemodel(self, model):
        model = Sequential()
        return model

    def modelsettings(self, InputSize, TotalActionCount, model):


        print("Settings ActionCount(+1): " + str(TotalActionCount))


        model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(InputSize, 1), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())  
        model.add(Dense(48, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))                           
        model.add(Dense(TotalActionCount + 1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='linear'))    

        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

        return model

    def ChangeLearningRate(self, model, NewRate):
        model.optimizer.learning_rate.assign(NewRate)

    def LoadBrain(self, FileName, model):
        del model
        print("Loading: " + FileName)

        model = models.load_model(FileName, compile=True)

        return model


    def SaveBrain(self, FileName, model):

        print("Saving: " + FileName)    
        model.save(FileName)


    def StateArray(self, InputArray):

        NewArray = InputArray.reshape(1, InputArray.size, 1)
        return NewArray


    def AIAction(self, CurrentState, model):
        Q = model.predict(CurrentState)            
        print("Q: " + str(Q))
        HighestQ = np.amax(Q)                       
        CurrentAction = np.argmax(Q)                
        return CurrentAction, HighestQ

    def Action(self, CurrentState, ActionCount, epsilon, model):
        CurrentAction = 0
        HighestQ = 0


        if np.random.rand() <= epsilon:
            CurrentAction = round(np.random.rand() * ActionCount)
        else:
            CurrentAction, HighestQ = self.AIAction(CurrentState, model)
        return CurrentAction, HighestQ


    def Eval(self, Datum, gamma, model):
        # order of elements inside Datum: (LastState, LastAction, Reward, CurrentState)

        Inputs = Datum[0]
        Targets = model.predict(Datum[0])
        Q_sa = model.predict(Datum[3])

        TotalReward = Datum[2] + gamma * np.max(Q_sa)

        Targets[0][Datum[1]] = TotalReward

        PrintLoss = model.train_on_batch(Inputs, Targets)

        print("PrintLoss: " + str(PrintLoss[0]))


        return PrintLoss[0], model








class Stuff:

    BrainSet = BrainFunctions()

    DataList = deque()

    model = Sequential()

    LossList = []



    def RunStuff(self):

        #for simplicity's sake, I left out a little code.  
        #I get input values through an http client at this section.
        #Those values include:
        #FunctionChoice,TotalActionCount,InputSize,LoadFile,SaveFile,CurrentState,LastState,LastAction,Reward,epsilon,EvalEpochs,gamma

        #The http client chooses which function to use.
        #When the client chooses newbrain, all the other functionality works fine
        #When the client chooses savebrain, all the other functionality works fine

        #When the client chooses loadbrain, errors occur.
        #Those errors occur at the "getlearningrate" choice and at the "evaluatedeque" choice






        OutputString = "NothingDone"


        if FunctionChoice == "newbrain":
            self.model = self.BrainSet.initializemodel(self.model)
            self.model = self.BrainSet.modelsettings(int(InputSize), int(TotalActionCount), self.model)
            OutputString = "NewBrainDone"

        if FunctionChoice == "loadbrain":
            self.model = self.BrainSet.LoadBrain(LoadFile, self.model)
            OutputString = "LoadBrainDone"

                #No errors occur here.  However, after this code is triggered (the "loadbrain" code), errors begin to occur.


        if FunctionChoice == "savebrain":
            self.BrainSet.SaveBrain(SaveFile, self.model)
            OutputString = "SaveBrainDone"

        if FunctionChoice == "getlearningrate":
            OutputString = str(backend.eval(self.model.optimizer.learning_rate))

                #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                #Error Message triggers here:  
                #OutputString = str(backend.eval(self.model.optimizer.learning_rate))
                #AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'learning_rate'

        if FunctionChoice == "moveandrecord":

            ConvertedCState = self.BrainSet.StateArray(CurrentState)
            ConvertedLState = self.BrainSet.StateArray(LastState)
            self.DataList.append((ConvertedLState, LastAction, Reward, ConvertedCState))
            CurrentAction, HighestQ = self.BrainSet.Action(ConvertedCState, TotalActionCount, epsilon, self.model)


        if FunctionChoice == "evaluatedeque":

            SampleQuantity = EvalEpochs
            SamplePercent = 1
            if SampleQuantity < len(self.DataList):
                SamplePercent = SampleQuantity / len(self.DataList)

            TotalTest = 0
            LossTotal = 0
            LossAverage = 0
            for Datum in self.DataList:

                if np.random.rand() <= SamplePercent:
                    TotalTest += 1

                    LossValue, self.model = self.BrainSet.Eval(Datum, gamma, self.model)

                    #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    #Error Message triggers here:
                    #PrintLoss = model.train_on_batch(Inputs, Targets)
                    #line 1340, in train_on_batch
                    #self._assert_compile_was_called()
                    #line 1635, in _assert_compile_was_called
                    #raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before '
                    #RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.

                    LossTotal += LossValue  

            if TotalTest > 0: 
                LossAverage = LossTotal/TotalTest

            if DequeSize:
                if len(self.DataList) > DequeSize:
                    for i in range(0, DequeSize - len(self.DataList)):
                        self.DataList.popleft()
```

I have new information.  I tried the model.summary command after loading the model.  This is encouraging.  The model does in fact open as you can below.  However, it doesn't work.  When I attempt a train_on_batch, I get the following error: "RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`."

Of course, immediately after this, I added a compile command, but the error persists.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 17, 1)             2
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 17)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 48)                864
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 24)                1176
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 75
=================================================================
Total params: 2,117
Trainable params: 2,117
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I've discovered more:  I can create a model, train it, and predict with it.  I can save that model.  I can then delete that model.  I can then load that model.  It seems to still function.  However, if I restart the program and then try to load the model, it does not function.  I get the same compile errors.

Comment: You need to include the code that uses these functions, exactly at the points where you get errors

Comment: Please specify if you are using keras to save model or tensorflow.keras to save model? Default save is changed in tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: overflow95.  I tried both.  First I used keras.  Then I used tensorflow.keras.  I used both the .h5 and the Tensor SaveModel methods.  Neither worked.

Comment: Matias Valdenegro:  I added a more complete code to the original question.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the keras API incorrectly. Loading a model using `your_keras_model.load_model` loads weights into the model directly. The object is mutated during the call, so you don't need to set it to `model` again.

You should be doing something like this instead.

```
# your code, does not work
# model = model.load_model(weight_path, compile=True)

# working code
model.load_weights(weight_path, compile=True)
model.evaluate(...)
```

Comment: I didn't use load_model through my model.  I used the models class.  (I tried first keras.models and then I tried tensorflow.keras.models)

model = models.load_model(FileName, compile=True)

Comment: Just to clarify.  This doesn't solve my issue.  Does anyone know why the load_model isn't working for me?